# changes to be done in twitter api 1.1

Tags: twitter

can any one please explain me the basic important changes that are to be done in API v1.1

I want to develop a web application that uses the Twitter API.v1.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you seen the overview of version 1.1? https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview

- JSON support only (no more XML, Atom, or RSS support)
- Authentication required on all endpoints (requiring applications to authenticate all of their requests with OAuth 1.0a)
- Default entities and retweet (where applicable, entities and retweets will now be returned by default)

Comment: can u plz tell me the basic changes